# In C, what would happen if I put 'successive wchar_t characters' into a wchar_t variable?

Tags: c, memory, binary, wchar-t

```
#include <stdio.h>

wchar_t wc = L' 459';
printf("%d", wc);           //result : 32
```

I know the 'space' is 'decimal 32' in ASCII code table.

What I don't understand is, as far as I know, if there's not enough space for a variable to store value, the value would be the 'last digits' of the original value.

Like, if I put binary value '1100 1001 0011 0110' into single byte variable, it would be '0011 0110' which is 'the last byte' of the original binary value.

But the code above shows 'the first byte' of the original value.

I'd like to know what happen in memory level when I execute the code above.

Comment: According to the C specification, "*The value of a wide character constant containing
more than one multibyte character or a single multibyte character that maps to multiple members of the extended execution character set, or containing a multibyte character or escape sequence not represented in the extended execution character set, is implementation-defined.*"

Comment: For example, Microsoft's MSVC (cl) and GNU GCC (gcc) set `wc` to different values. MSVC sets it to `L' '` and GCC sets it to `L'9'`. Both compilers will issue a warning about the truncation if you set the warning level high enough.

Comment: `wchar_t` is 4 bytes in Linux, and 2 bytes in Windows. Either way `wchar_t wc = L' 459'` is not valid. Describe what system do you work on and what is your goal.

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani It runs without any warning on VS2019. My goal is 'to know how it really works on memory level'. As far as I've learned, there's no problem on my code because 'wchar_t' is typedef of 'unsigened short' in VS and the Character Literal Prefix 'L' represents the value is 'wchar_t type' so I don't see any problem on my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_int64 x = 0x0041'0042'0043'0044ULL;
printf("%016llx\n", x);             //prints 0041004200430044

wchar_t wc;
wc = x;
printf("%04X\n", wc);               //prints 0044 as you expect

wc = L'\x0041\x0042\x0043\x0044';   //prints 0041, uses the first character
printf("%04X\n", wc);
```

If you assign an integer value that's too large, the compiler takes the max value `0x0044` that fits in 2 bytes.

If you try to assign several elements in to one element, the compiler takes the first element `0x0041` which fits. `L'x'` is mean to be a single wide character.

---

VS2019 will issue a warning for `wchar_t wc = L' 459'`, unless warning level is set to less than 3, but that's not recommended. Use warning level 3 or higher.

`wchar_t` is a primitive type, not a `typedef` for `unsigned short`, but they are both 2 bytes in Windows (4 bytes in linux)

Note that `'abcd'` is 4 bytes. The `L` prefix indicates 2 bytes per element (in Windows), so `L'abcd'` is 8 bytes.

To see what is inside `wc`, lets look at Unicode character `L'X'` which has UTF-16 encoding of `0x0058` (similar to ASCII values up to 128)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    wchar_t wc = L'X';
    wprintf(L"%c\n", wc);
    char buf[256];
    memcpy(buf, &wc, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        printf("%02X ", buf[i] & 0xff);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be `58 00`. It is not `00 58` because Windows runs on little-endian systems and the bytes are flipped.

Another weird thing is that UTF16 uses for 4 bytes for some code points. So you will get a warning for this line:

```
wchar_t wc = L'';
```

Instead you want to use string:

```
wchar_t *wstr = L"";
::MessageBoxW(0, wstr, 0, 0); //console may not display this correctly
```

This string will be 6 bytes (2 elements + null terminating char)

Comment: I can't fully understand what this answer mean and I still can't figure out what's going on my code but thanks for the answer anyway. If you could elaborate the exact data process on memory level when 'wchar_t wc = L' 459' executes, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `L' 459'` is 8 bytes, it doesn't fit in `wc` which is 2 bytes. The compiler ignores (459) it just uses the first character `wc = L' ';` Run this code: `wprintf(L"[%c] %04X", wc, wc)` the result will be `"[ ] 0020"` (blank space and its ASCII value).  -- Are you thinking of `const wchar_t *str = L"1234"`?

Comment: But when I do "wchar_t wc = ' 459'", the result of "printf("%d", wc)" is "13625" which is the "last" 2bytes of the original 4byte value. What I don't understand is, why printf of L" 459" shows the 'space' part while the printf of " 459" shows the '59' part. It's completely opposite to each other.

Comment: wchar_t wc = ' 459' AND printf using %d = shows '13625'. wchar_t wc = L' 459' AND printf using %d = shows '32'. I'd like to know the difference of memory data between ' 459' and L' 459'.

Comment: `13625` is `0x3539`, it corresponds to the ASCII values for the last 2 characters in `' 459'`. Assigning `' 459'` to `wchar_t` is invalid. The compiler treats `' 459'` as a 4-byte integer, then tries to match it to `wchar_t` as described in the answer.